# Using VBA to Create Microsoft Word Document Templates

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, document

One of my clients requires my help to create corporate document templates in Microsoft Word - from letter, fax to memo.

Here are some of the requirements:

- Fixed sections with no changes to font type, size and color
- Fixed sections but the admin is able to edit the content
- Placements of Sections (e.g. 3cm margin)
- User is able to choose if they want a section displayed
- A body text content that will be left blank but users can key in.
- A different set of rules/formatting for the continuation pages (page 2>)

Just wanted to tap on the brains of all the VBA experts here and learn what is the best way to approach this. I understand that Word Document allows you to create templates and content locking - is that sufficient? I believe with Macro, the client can have stricter control (creating menus to select the required template, and forms to input the information).

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Cheers,
Alvin

Comment: This does not seem to be a specific question about programming.

Comment: @TimWilliams it's about programming, but the question is too broad - it covers too many aspects of template creation. Alviin, the IT Pro forum on the Microsoft TechNet site would probably be the better place to have this discussion.

Comment: @AlvinLim It would also be better if at least we can see some of your codes so that we may not start from the scratch. Thanks!